# How to enable Axis (Web Services) logging in unix server?

Tags: axis

```
    How to enable Axis (Web Services) logging in unix server??
```

Im trying to enable the axis in the unix server. But didnt know how to do it. Found this link "http://maximodev.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-enable-web-services-logging.html" but didnt find the file(common-logging.properties) file.

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: This question might be better for [Server Fault SE](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How can we enable axis for the project that is already deployed into some environment?

Comment: I want to see an xml coming from someother system.(because Im getting an error for some kind of transactions.But I want to see tha whole xml(having error) coming from other system.For doing this I have to enable the axis.)

Comment: on cmdline you can add this -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime=true -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire=debug -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient=debug